# webbrowser.get("firefox") on a Mac with Firefox "could not locate runnable browser"

Tags: python, macos, firefox, browser

I think what I need here is to know which magic command-line or OSA script program to run to start up a URL in an existing Firefox browser, if one is running, or to also start up Firefox if it isn't. On Mac.

I'm testing a Python program (Crunchy Python) which sets up a web server then uses Firefox for the front end. It starts the web application with the following:

```
try:
    client = webbrowser.get("firefox")
    client.open(url)
    return
except:
    try:
        client = webbrowser.get()
        client.open(url)
        return
    except:
        print('Please open %s in Firefox.' % url)
```

I have Safari on my Mac as the default, but I also have Firefox installed and running. The above code started the new URL (on localhost) in Safari. Crunchy does not work well in Safari. I want to see it in Firefox, since I do have Firefox. Under Python 2.5, 2.6, and 2.7 (from version control) I get this:

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.get("firefox")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/webbrowser.py", line 46, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

Firefox is there. I tried using webbrowser.get("/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox %s") which starts up a new instance of Firefox then complains that another instance of Firefox is already running.

I really would like webbrowser to open up the URL in an existing tab/window of Firefox, if it's already running, or in a new Firefox is not already running.

I looked at webbrowser.py and it looks like there is no 'firefox' support for MacOSX. That's okay, I can add that. But I don't know how to open the URL in Firefox in the way I want to.

Ideas? And for now, I can force Crunchy to give me the URL, which I can manually paste into Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Launch Services to open the URL.  You can do this with the `LaunchServices` module, or with Apple's `open` utility, or with my `launch` utility ([here](http://web.sabi.net/nriley/software/)):

`open` is probably easiest:

```
% open -b org.mozilla.firefox http://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

(or, of course, the equivalent in Python with `subprocess` or similar) should do what you want.

Comment: Really, Python's "webbrowser" should do that. If this is the right general answer then I'll contribute a patch to the main Python code, unless you want to be the one to do that?

Comment: I've added it to the Python bug tracker as issue 7192 (see http://bugs.python.org/issue7192 ). That includes a partial patch, but I don't think it's a full solution.

Answer (score 3):

Apple uses launch services to find applications. An application can be used by the open command - [Apple developer man page for open](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html)

The python command you want is

```
client = webbrowser.get("open -a /Applications/Firefox.app %s")
```

Following Nicholas Riley 's comment

If Firefox is on the list of Applications then you can get away with open -a Firefox.app %s

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code the path to Firefox; it can be installed anywhere.

Comment: "open -a /Applications/Firefox.app %s" doesn't work. Even from the command-line that opens a URL using Safari, my default browser. I dug around some and it seems to be a difference between OS X 10.4 (which I have) and 10.5. If I do "open -a Firefox %s" then it works. Another option (after looking around) is "open -b org.mozilla.firefox %s". Don't really know what a "bundle identifer" is, but various places uses that incantation. I'll use the -b version. Thanks for the clue!

Comment: A bundle identifier is a unique identifier for applications on Mac OS X (partial replacement for the four-byte "creator code").  Launch Services indexes bundle identifiers and type information in order to handle application/document/URL opening; if you want to see what kind of information it indexes, run /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump.

Comment: Just check with Monterey the command line I gave does still work from the command line but the bundle identifier is probably the best way to do this